# Rewriting the permalinks structure in WordPress custom post type / archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom post type with JetEngine and named it "cars-list" and created page in WordPress and named the page "Cars".

In wordpress Admin CP>Appearence>Menus, I have put the "Cars" page into navigation menu.

I also was able to add "cars-list" post-type to menu and dragged under the "Cars" page

If I go to frontend and go to any Cars archive page then it will show to breadcrumbs as Home>Cars list>somecar, but I want to show them as menu navigation is set: Home>Cars>Cars list>somecar.

How to achieve this?

I also tried to ask ChatGPT millions times, but the answers are all not functioning.